# VS 2008 : See the elements referred to pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008

This seems to be a rather stupid question, but I create a pointer to an array of doubles :

```
double* tab = new double[10];
```

Then I fill the double array, but when I expand the tab pointer in Debug Mode, I only *tab which gives me the value of first element, which is normal. But how do I see the other elements?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write in the watch window `tab,10` you'll see it as if its a 10 element array.

Be careful though because this can also show you stuff beyond the allocated length of the array.